# Relative dualising sheaf of cover of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, elliptic-curves, duality-theorems

I am trying to understand the relative dualising sheaf of a morphism of varieties in general but also in the special case of covers of the projective line by a elliptic curve, let us say of the form $Y=Spec(R) \to X=Spec(S)$ with $R=k[x,y]/(y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda))$ and $S=k[x]$ with the morphism coming from the inclusion.

In the literature I have found two different global descriptions of the dualising sheaf of a morphism by

1. $\mathcal{Hom}_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X}(f^{-1} \Omega_X, \Omega_Y)$
2. $(f^*\Omega_X)' \otimes \Omega_Y$

and the local description as

3. the coherent module associated to $\Omega_{R/S}$.

I would like to know how these concepts are related, so in the best case what an explicit isomorphism is. Especially, I am interested in what the image of the "canonical" element mapping $d \varphi \to d(\varphi \circ f)$ in the first case in concept $2$ and $3$ is.

This whole thing is quite confusing for me, as in my case I think $\Omega_X$ is just associated to the $k[x]$ module generated by $dx$ and $\Omega_Y$ is the $R$-module generated by $dx, dy$ modulo the relation $r=2ydy-(3x^2-2(\lambda+1)x-\lambda)dx$.

But then description $2$ gives me the module associated to $R[dy,dx,(dx)^{-1}]/r$ while concept $3$ gives me (as $dx=0$) just $R[dy]/2ydy$, and in none of these cases I am able to describe the "canonical element". So I would be grateful for some clarification.

Comment: Your terminology doesn't match what you're writing about - the object $\Omega_{Y/X}$ is the sheaf of differentials, which is related to but is not in general the same thing as the relative dualizing sheaf. Which of these objects is the one you're trying to understand?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I am trying to understand the relative dualising sheaf. Could you explain (or give a reference), so I can learn more about the relation/difference between these guys?

Comment: @Matthias Have a look at Liu's book on arithmetic curves and algebraic geometry. It has a section on the relative dualizing sheaf, and contains many useful references.